# Weak and strong properties example

Tags: objective-c, reference-counting

I am starting with Objective-C development and trying to understand the weak and strong references. I think I understand it, but I am not sure about it...

Let consider that code:

```
@interface SomeClass {} 
@property (nonatomic, weak) NSString* propertyName;
@end
```

Now, if I invoke somewhere in the code something like this:

`NSString* s = someClassInstance.propertyName;`

The reference counter is not incremented. Is my understanding correct?

- Doubt 1: What is the reference counter value for `propertyName`?
- Doubt 2: So... Could you give an example of when I can get the strong reference to this property? I hope you know what I mean or what I do not understand...

I will get the weak reference.

Comment: It's not the property that has a reference count.  It's the object that that property returns to you.  The property attributes just tell the compiler how the property should be synthesized.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Declaring `propertyName` as a "weak" property means two things:

1. When you assign an object to `propertyName`, that object's reference count is not incremented.
2. When the object that `propertyName` points to is deallocated, `propertyName` will be set to `nil`.

Assigning the value of `propertyName` to another variable may or may not have any impact on the reference count.  If you assign it to a `strong` property, you will almost certainly increase the refcount (since that is part of the semantics of a `strong` property).  But ultimately the compiler will decide if modifying the reference count is necessary.

It's important to understand the concept of object ownership in Objective-C, whether you are using ARC or not, but the details of the actual reference count for a given object at any given moment are not so useful.  Remember this: a `strong` property owns an object.  A `weak` property does not.

Comment: "Remember this: a strong property owns an object. A weak property does not." Very good line.

Comment: My doubt is when we take an outlet of a UIView, sometimes it is required to take Strong, otherwise if it is not added to the view, many time app crashes or we have a nil object ? Have you faced ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all
"strong" is synonym of "retain" and "weak" is synonym for "assign" in ARC enabled application.

answer to Doubt 1:
Its retain count will be equal to the retain count of the object it is storing. as it is just a reference.

answer to Doubt 2

Answer to your doubts:

You should refer this link for understanding strong and weak type property

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5677/beginning-arc-in-ios-5-part-1

Comment: weak and assign are actually not synonymous. In @SeamusCampbell's answer above he makes 2 points about a weak variable. The 2nd point, "When the object that propertyName points to is deallocated, propertyName will be set to nil." is not true of assigned variables.

Comment: 2peter I have seen that assign is used only for primitive variables only like int, float, char etc, is it true?